# Set the default run level of sles 12

Tags: suse

I tryed creating /etc/inittab
and adding
id:3:initdefault:

But its skipped and goes straight to init 5.

How do I configure this via configure file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/etc/inittab` file is not used anymore.

> ```
> # systemd uses 'targets' instead of runlevels. By default, there are two main targets:
> #
> # multi-user.target: analogous to runlevel 3
> # graphical.target: analogous to runlevel 5
> #
> # To set a default target, run:
> #
> # ln -s /lib/systemd/system/<target name>.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
> ```

Comment: thanks, I have been away from linux for about 10 years. Did not expect this or find it documented anywhere obvious.